# Host declaration on AKS doesn't work on nginx ingress

Tags: azure, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I use AKS v1.26.6 and ingress-nginx v1.8.1 and I need to have multiple hosts declared in ingress rules
Without `host` declaration it works:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  ingressClassName: ingress-nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: aks-helloworld-one
            port:
              number: 80
```

..with `host` in rules it doesn't (gives timeout):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  ingressClassName: ingress-nginx
  rules:
  - host: nginx-basic-auth-az-cli.demo.kagarlickij.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: aks-helloworld-one
            port:
              number: 80
```

On my local `docker-desktop` cluster it works with `host` rule, problem is only with AKS
Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: it seems like you don't use rewrite-target in host. try without use-regex and rewrite-target. here are some information about that: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Comment: @ibram I've removed both and it didn't help

Comment: could you try this: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /