Terraform Kubernetes NGINX Ingress - Host rules not returning 504 (Gateway Timeout)
I am trying to specify different hosts (subdomains) to different Kubernetes Services within my Kubernetes NGINX Ingress. For reference I am using Azure AKS.
I have the following ingress declared in Terraform.
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name             = "nginx-ingress"
  repository       = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart            = "ingress-nginx"
  namespace        = "ingress-nginx"
  create_namespace = true
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.type"
    value = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "nginx_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "nginx-ingress"
  }

  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "nginx"

    rule {
      host = "front-end.mydomain.com" # disable to access both hosts
      http {
        path {
          path      = "/"
          path_type = "Prefix"
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service_v1.front_end.metadata[0].name
              port {
                number = 80
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    rule {
      host = "docs.mydomain.com"
      http {
        path {
          path      = "/"
          path_type = "Prefix"
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service_v1.front_end.metadata[0].name
              port {
                number = 80
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

This is what happens with different configurations.

If I have one host set, both sites are accessible over HTTP on their domains.


If I have no hosts set, no sites are accessible over HTTP on their domains.


If I have both hosts set, no sites are accessible over HTTP on their domains.

I do not currently understand why this is occurring. I have confirmed the DNS A records point towards the correct IP address of the load balancer/ingress for each subdomain.
Edit: Fixed missing curly brace

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053330/host-declaration-on-aks-doesnt-work-on-nginx-ingress

So you are not using the rewrite-target annotation?

@MarkoE I am not, though I have tried that and it makes no difference.

After significant tinkering, I have resolved the issue.
The solution was to set the below on the NGINX ingress controller declared using the helm release provider.
# Required for SSL/TLS self-check to succeed (cert-manager)
set {
  name  = "controller.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"
  value = "/healthz"
}

# Required for host path routing to succeed
set {
  name  = "controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy"
  value = "Local"
}

Updated complete example below.
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name             = "nginx-ingress"
  repository       = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart            = "ingress-nginx"
  namespace        = "ingress-nginx"
  create_namespace = true
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.type"
    value = "LoadBalancer"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"
    value = "/healthz"
  }
  set {
    name  = "controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy"
    value = "Local"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "nginx_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "nginx-ingress"
  }

  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "nginx"

    rule {
      host = "front-end.mydomain.com"
      http {
        path {
          path      = "/"
          path_type = "Prefix"
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service_v1.front_end.metadata[0].name
              port {
                number = 80
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    rule {
      host = "docs.mydomain.com"
      http {
        path {
          path      = "/"
          path_type = "Prefix"
          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service_v1.front_end.metadata[0].name
              port {
                number = 80
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    tls {
      hosts = [
        "front-end.mydomain.com",
        "docs.mydomain.com"
      ]
      secret_name = "letsencrypt-tls"
    }
  }
}


This is a normal behavior, because you have an issue in your parentheses.
rule { # STARTS HERE
  host = "front-end.mydomain.com" # this will be the only domain
  http {
    path {
      path      = "/"
      path_type = "Prefix"
      backend {
        service {
          name = kubernetes_service_v1.front_end.metadata[0].name
          port {
            number = 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

rule {
  host = "docs.mydomain.com"
  http {
    path {
      path      = "/"
      path_type = "Prefix"
      backend {
        service {
          name = kubernetes_service_v1.front_end.metadata[0].name
          port {
            number = 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} # ENDS HERE
}

but according to this, you can only define one host in each rule.
The following may work:
rule {
  host = "front-end.mydomain.com"
  http {
    path {
      path      = "/"
      path_type = "Prefix"
      backend {
        service {
          name = kubernetes_service_v1.front_end.metadata[0].name
          port {
            number = 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}

rule {
  host = "docs.mydomain.com"
  http {
    path {
      path      = "/"
      path_type = "Prefix"
      backend {
        service {
          name = kubernetes_service_v1.front_end.metadata[0].name
          port {
            number = 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}


Thanks for identifying the typo, an error with me pasting into stackoverflow, not the original config (masked some values). Updated for future viewers.

You are correct that according to the docs it is only one host per rule. I believe this is correct in my original example (after the typo fix).

@BadgerHobbs so is it not fixed?

I'm afraid not, no.
